# Error in `validate_index()`: ! Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA` using modeltime package in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm having trouble visualizing and calibrating time series using the modeltime package. In the following code, I encounter two similar errors:

```
# Webscrape

webpage <- read_html("https://www.westmetall.com/en/markdaten.php?action=table&field=LME_Al_cash")
alu_table <- html_nodes(webpage, "table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
alu_df <- map_dfr(alu_table, magrittr::extract, c("date", "LME Aluminium Cash-Settlement"))

# Names

names(alu_df)[1] <- "Date"
names(alu_df)[2] <- "Aluminium_Prices"

# Clear rows in data frame 

alu_df_cleaned <- alu_df %>% 
  # Remove unwanted rows
  filter(Date != "date" & Aluminium_Prices != "LME Aluminium Cash-Settlement")

# Change Date type

alu_df_cleaned$Date <- dmy(alu_df_cleaned$Date)

# Proper structure of integers to translate them to the numeric class

alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices <- gsub(",", "", alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices)
alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices <- as.numeric(alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices)

# Sorting prices by Date

alu_df_cleaned <- alu_df_cleaned %>% 
  arrange(Date)

# Check if there are any NA's 

sum(is.na(alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices))

df_na <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    map(
      map(alu_df_cleaned$Aluminium_Prices, is.na), sum)
    )
  )

rownames(subset(df_na, df_na$V1 != 0))

# Convert to tibble

alu_ts_data <- alu_df_cleaned %>% 
  mutate(row_name = row_number()) %>% 
  tsibble::as_tsibble(index = Date, key = row_name)

# Drop NA's from the dataset

alu_ts_data <- alu_ts_data %>% 
  drop_na()

# Split the data into train and test 

set.seed(1353)
splits <- initial_time_split(alu_ts_data)

train <- training(splits)
test <- testing(splits)

# Visualise the Splits
splits %>% 
  tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>% 
  plot_time_series_cv_plan(.date_var = Date,
                           .value = Aluminium_Prices)

Error in `validate_index()`:
! Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Backtrace:
  1. splits %>% tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>% ...
 10. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(., .value)
 11. tidyr::unchop(...)
 12. tidyr:::df_unchop(...)
 13. vctrs::list_unchop(col, ptype = col_ptype)
 14. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 16. tsibble:::vec_restore.tbl_ts(x = x, to = to)
 17. tsibble::build_tsibble(...)
 18. tsibble:::validate_index(tbl, !!qindex)
Error in validate_index(tbl, !!qindex) :
```

```
# Multiple models

# Auto ARIMA Model
arima_auto_fit <- arima_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("auto_arima") %>% 
  fit(Aluminium_Prices ~ Date, data = train)

# Boosted ARIMA Model 
arima_boost_fit <- arima_boost() %>% 
  set_engine("auto_arima_xgboost") %>% 
  fit(Aluminium_Prices ~ Date, data = train)

# Exponential Smoothing Model 
ets_fit <- exp_smoothing() %>% 
  set_engine("ets") %>% 
  fit(Aluminium_Prices ~ Date, data = train)

# Prophet Model 
prophet_fit <- prophet_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("prophet") %>% 
  fit(Aluminium_Prices ~ Date, data = train)

# Linear Model 
lm_fit <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>% 
  fit(Aluminium_Prices ~ Date, data = train)

# Put in Table and Calibrate

models_tbl <- modeltime_table(
  arima_auto_fit,
  arima_boost_fit,
  ets_fit,
  prophet_fit,
  lm_fit
)

# Calibrate 

calibrate_tbl <- models_tbl %>% 
  modeltime::modeltime_calibrate(new_data = test, quiet = FALSE)

Error: Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Error: Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Error: Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Error: Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.
Error: Column `Date` (index) must not contain `NA`.

── Model Calibration Failure Report ────────────────────────
All models failed Modeltime Calibration:
- Model 1: Failed Calibration.
- Model 2: Failed Calibration.
- Model 3: Failed Calibration.
- Model 4: Failed Calibration.
- Model 5: Failed Calibration.

Potential Solution: Use `modeltime_calibrate(quiet = FALSE)` AND Check the Error/Warning Messages for clues as to why your model(s) failed calibration.
── End Model Calibration Failure Report ────────────────────

Error in `validate_modeltime_calibration()`:
! All models failed Modeltime Calibration.
Backtrace:
 1. models_tbl %>% ...
 3. modeltime:::modeltime_calibrate.mdl_time_tbl(...)
 4. modeltime:::validate_modeltime_calibration(ret)
Error in validate_modeltime_calibration(ret)
```

I attempted to see if there were any NAs in my dataset and I have found two. Then I have droped them, but nothing has resolved the problem. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: P.S. list of used packages: library(rvest)
library(tidyverse) 
library(tidymodels)
library(lubridate)
library(timetk)
library(modeltime)
library(fpp3)
library(xgboost)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)

Comment: I don't think it's directly related to this, however for people who have come across this 
Ensure your data is of the right type. It appeared to be that I was passing a `tsibble` object around (rather that a `tibble`)

Running `data %>% as_tibble()` pre the fitting process, sorted my issues out.